# Javascript search in string from array of values

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I search in string from a array with values without a each?

Something like this:

```
this.preImage.src.search(['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif']);
```

Comment: If by `without a each` you mean 'without a loop', then you can't. You would *have* to loop through the array.

Comment: what do you expect to get as the result? boolean? Or index of the first occurence? This can be done through custom function but not without using loop

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan actually one could create a regexp and search without a loop :)

Comment: The best way without using a loop is to use the [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method of array.

Comment: @AlexeyTen there's still a loop happening though, you just don't have it in your code :)

Comment: Though honestly every way of doing it uses a loop, even if it hides the loop from you.

Comment: If you really want go this way, ten techically in processor code there always be a loop  :)

Comment: Seriously, from you example I guess you want to find out if `src` end with one of these extensions. Am I right?

Comment: `/(jpe?g|png|gif)$/.test(this.preImage.src)`

Comment: No Alexey, the this.preImage.src is a base64 string.

Comment: If you write, your input, and your output, I can help u, :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a constructed regular expression (inspired by @Alexey Ten's comment)

```
var endings = ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif']
var regexp = new RegExp('(' + endings.join('|') + ')', 'i')
var isimg = regexp.test(this.preImage.src);
```

`isimg` will be true if the string contains any of the endings in any (upper- or lower-) case

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked into jQuery.inArray()? That might help you. Documentation Link: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/

```
function check_array(array,search_term){    
     response = $.inArray( search_term, array);
   if(response < 0){
     response = "not found";
   }else{
     response = "found at " + response;
   }
     return response;
}
```

jsFiddle Example - https://jsfiddle.net/cnag4yuL/